# Prove that $ AA^T=0\implies A = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with real entries, where $n\geq2$.
>   Let $AA^T = [b_{ij}] $, where $A^T $ is the transpose of $A$. If
>   $b_{11} + b_{22 }+\cdots+ b_{nn} = 0$, show that $A = 0$.

From what I've gleaned so far, $AA^T$ is a symmetric matrix, and the diagonals are zero. I can't figure out how to solve this question. Is there some property that exists that I'm missing for handling this question?

Comment: Hint: If $x,y,...,z$ are real numbers, then the solution of the equation $x^2 +y^2 +...+z^2=0$ is $x=0,y=0,...,z=0$

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Learn latex quickly

Comment: Your problems on title and the content are different.

Comment: Sorry for the improper formatting! Thanks for the link Kamal, They were really helpful :) and thanks JohnD for the edit!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let

$$A=(a_{ij})\implies A^t=(a_{ji})\implies AA^t=(b_{ij})=\left(\sum_{k=1}^ma_{ik}a_{jk}\right)$$

so that

$$0=\sum_{i=1}^nb_{ii}=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^na_{ik}a_{ik}$$

Complete the proof now.

Comment: Forgive me, my linear algebra is pretty bad, thats the sum of the multiplication of diagonal entries = 0 yes? is it sufficient then to say that as the sum is zero, either aik or ajk must equal to zero. Thus, since A = Atranspose, Both A and A transpose are zero?

Comment: @Waffleboy, this is not a matter of linear algebra but only algebra: we have $\;a_{ik}a_{ik}=a_{ik}^2\;$ , and since we're in the reals, the sum of squares equals zero iff all the summands are zero.

Comment: I'm also new to Linear Algebra and I'm wondering whether you intended to say $(b_{ij})=\left(\sum_{k=1}^ma_{ik}a_{kj}\right)$ instead? Also, this isn't explicitly stated, but you've assumed A to be a matrix with n rows and m columns right? And of course, thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

$||A||=\sqrt{\sum_{i,j=1}^n |a_{ij}|^2}$

i.e.  $||A||=\sqrt {trace(A^t A)}$ .Now  by the given condition $b_{11}+b_{22}+...+b_{nn}=0$

i.e. trace of $A^tA=0$

i.e. $||A||=0$ if and only if $A=0$

Answer (score 4):

$\forall X \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $X^tAA^tX=0$, i.e. $\left<A^tX, A^tX\right>=0$, hence $A^tX=0, \forall X \in \mathbb {R}^n$, so $A^t=0$, thus $A=0$.

Comment: I dont't really see why if $X^tAA^tX=0$ $\forall X$, then $A^tX=0$. For me, if you call $A^tX=B$, we are just resaying that $BB^t=0$ implies $B=0$. Can you clarify?

Answer (score -1):

I thought about this proof, but I think it is not totally correct:

Supose $A≠0$.

Then, for any $X$, $A+X≠X$.

Multiplying by $A^T$ at the right, we get:

$(A+X)A^T≠XA^T$

$AA^T+XA^T≠XA^T$

$XA^T≠XA^T$

Arriving in a contradiction, we get $A=0$.
I realise it may not be totally correct to multiply by $A^T$ without making some proper assumptions, but I know I can pick any $X$. Is there a way to formalise this proof?